# Auto Update Woocommerce Checkout when Remove Item is clicked or Quantity is changed with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to update checkout using ajax when the remove item or when quantity selector is clicked on checkout page.

My **/checkout/order-review.php** is not using default woo table, the code is as follows:

```
    <?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>

<h3 class="order-review">  <?php $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
echo sprintf( _n( ' Your Order (%d item)', ' Your Order (%d items)', $count ), $count ); ?> </h3>

<?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
        

<div class="cart-item-wrap <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
        <div class="i-order-item i-card cart_item  " data-product-id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-item-key="<?php echo $cart_item_key ?>">
        <div class="item__image">
                        <div class="ll-image u-pb-0">
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                        
                                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item__content">
            <div class="item__info">
                <h3>
                    
                    <?php   echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                                    

                                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                        // Meta data
                                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );

                                        // Backorder notification
                                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </h3>
                                <div class="quantity-wrapper <?php if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) { } else { ?>product-quantity<?php } ?>">       
                <?php if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) { } else { ?>
                                                                    <span class="u-mr-5">Quantity</span>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php
                                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                                        } else {
                                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                                'max_value'   => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                                'min_value'   => '0',
                                                'product_name'  => $_product->get_name(),
                                            ), $_product, false );
                                        }

                                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                                    ?>
                    
                                                    <span class="product-remove">

                                       <?php
                                        echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                            'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                            sprintf(
                                                '<a href="%s" class="u-black remove-cart-item edit-cart" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">Remove</a>',
                                                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                                esc_attr( $cart_item_key )
                                            ),
                                            $cart_item_key
                                        );
                                    ?>
                                    </span>
                </div>
                            </div>
            <div class="item__price">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    ?>         
</div>
        </div>
            
    </div>

</div>
<?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
```

I USE THE FOLLOWING IN **function.php** to ajax the process which is not working

```
// jQuery - Ajax script
function action_wp_footer() {
    // Only checkout page
    if ( ! is_checkout() )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(document).on('click', '.cart_item a.remove-cart-item', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).attr("data-product_id"),
        cart_item_key = $(this).attr("data-cart_item_key"),
        product_container = $(this).parents('.shop_table');

    // Add loader
    product_container.block({
        message: null,
        overlayCSS: {
            cursor: 'none'
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: "product_remove",
            product_id: product_id,
            cart_item_key: cart_item_key
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if ( ! response || response.error )
                return;

            var fragments = response.fragments;

            // Replace fragments
            if ( fragments ) {
                $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                    $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

});
    </script>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );


function warp_ajax_product_remove()
{
    // Get order review fragment
    ob_start();
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item)
    {
        if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] && $cart_item_key == $_POST['cart_item_key'] )
        {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        }
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();

    woocommerce_order_review();
    $woocommerce_order_review = ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
```

THE PROBLEM:

1. When I change the product quantity nothing happens
2. When I click the remove item link the page does not update in ajax either does it reload.
   But if I reload the page manually after clicking the remove link, the product will be removed.

Any help is appreciated on how to make the page auto update using ajax when quantity is selected or when remove item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WooCommerce trigger `update_checkout`. I revised your code. There are some code missing and bugs in your code. try the below code.

in **`/checkout/order-review.php`** replace with the below code.

```
<div class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <h3 class="order-review">  <?php $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        echo sprintf( _n( ' Your Order (%d item)', ' Your Order (%d items)', $count ), $count ); ?> </h3>
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );
        
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
    <div class="cart-item-wrap <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
        <div class="i-order-item i-card cart_item  " data-product-id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-item-key="<?php echo $cart_item_key ?>">
            <div class="item__image">
                <div class="ll-image u-pb-0">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__content">
                <div class="item__info">
                    <h3>
                        <?php   echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            
                            // Meta data
                            echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
                            
                            // Backorder notification
                            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                            }
                            ?>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="quantity-wrapper <?php if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) { } else { ?>product-quantity<?php } ?>">       
                        <?php if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) { } else { ?>
                        <span class="u-mr-5">Quantity</span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php
                            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                $product_quantity = sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                            } else {
                                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'   => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'   => '0',
                                    'product_name'  => $_product->get_name(),
                                ), $_product, false );
                            }
                            
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                            ?>
                        <span class="product-remove">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s" class="u-black remove-cart-item edit-cart" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">Remove</a>',
                                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                    esc_attr( $cart_item_key )
                                ),
                                $cart_item_key
                            );
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item__price">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
</div>
```

in **`functions.php`** **JavaScript and AJAX.**

```
// jQuery - Ajax script
function action_wp_footer() {
    // Only checkout page
    if ( ! is_checkout() )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            $(document).on('click', '.cart_item a.remove-cart-item', function (e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var product_id = $(this).attr("data-product_id"),
                    cart_item_key = $(this).attr("data-cart_item_key"),
                    product_container = $(this).parents('#order_review');

                // Add loader
                product_container.block({
                    message: null,
                    overlayCSS: {
                        cursor: 'none'
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        action: "product_remove",
                        product_id: product_id,
                        cart_item_key: cart_item_key
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        product_container.unblock();
                        $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );

function warp_ajax_product_remove(){

    // Get order review fragment
    ob_start();
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item){
        if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] && $cart_item_key == $_POST['cart_item_key'] ){
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        }
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();
    wp_send_json_success();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhautik but unfortunately your answer does remove the product with ajax but no update on the product total amounts and no woocommerce notice about the product removal and quantity select does not update when changed.

Comment: @JoeTitus well you got answer already which you asked intially in your question. and now you are asking more than that which is also you haven't tried yet yourself. please produce minimal code for of requirement. in your question, you didn't ask about the **total amount**, **WooCommerce notice on removal**, and I didn't answer for **select does not update when changed** because you didn't code for that. remember this is not a coding service. for asking for help you have to produce a minimal example of whatever you asking.